# Un-Recognized Selector Sent to Instance Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am building my App after adding some code but I get the Un-Recongnized Selector Sent to Instance Error stopping my App from running. Here's a Picture of the Error -

[alt text http://www.grabup.com/uploads/20f66eecee4bd96198c7bbcfe647ec74.png?direct](http://www.grabup.com/uploads/20f66eecee4bd96198c7bbcfe647ec74.png?direct)

This is the Code I added (it's for the data source of an NSOutlineView)

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialization code, rootsObjects is a NSArray instance variable
        rootObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Joshua", @"Erne", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

// here NSOutlineView asks how many children rows to display for a given item
- (int)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
    // if item is nil this should be a Root row, else I pass 0 for example but should be the count of objects contained in item
    return (item == nil) ? [rootObjects count] : 0;
}

// here NSOutlineView asks if a given item can be expanded i.e contains children
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    // again I return YES for example, but should be based on the count of objects contained in item
    return YES; //(item == nil) ? YES : ([item numberOfChildren] != -1);
}

// here NSOutlineView asks for the object (some treelike structure) assigned to the nth index child row of item 
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
            child:(int)index
           ofItem:(id)item
{
    // if item is nil I opass the appropriate Root row, else I pass nil for example but should be an object contained in item
    return (item == nil) ? [rootObjects objectAtIndex:index] : nil;
}

// here NSOutlineView asks for the objectValue (usually a NSString)) to be displayed in tableColumn for the given item
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
           byItem:(id)item
{
    // pass the object we want to display in the tableColumn for item
    return item ;
    // here I pass item for example since I know it's a NSString, but usually will be something to compute.
    // the [tableColumn identifier] property (that can be set in Interface Builder) is very useful here.
}

// here NSOutlineView asks for the NSCell to be used by tableColumn for the given item
- (NSCell *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)ov 
 dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
                   item:(id)item 
{
    // the nil tableColumn represents the unified root row style
    if (tableColumn == nil) {
        // pass a cell we want to be used as root row (assume we've have assigned "Name" as identifier of some tableColumn)
        return [[treeTable tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"Name"] dataCell];
    }
    // else just pass the default cell
    return [tableColumn dataCellForRow:[treeTable rowForItem:item]];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item {
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the Code I have in the same file (the Datasource) as the code above.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {  

    dragType = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   @"factorialDragType", nil];

    [ dragType retain ]; 

    [ treeTable registerForDraggedTypes:dragType ];
    NSSortDescriptor* sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
    [groupTreeControl setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: sortDesc]];
    [ sortDesc release ];
}   


//------------------------------------
#pragma mark NSOutlineView datasource methods -- see NSOutlineViewDataSource
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
- (BOOL) outlineView : (NSOutlineView *) outlineView 
          writeItems : (NSArray*) items 
        toPasteboard : (NSPasteboard*) pboard {

    [ pboard declareTypes:dragType owner:self ];        
    // items is an array of _NSArrayControllerTreeNode see http://theocacao.com/document.page/130 for more info
    draggedNode = [ items objectAtIndex:0 ];

    return YES; 
}




- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)item childIndex:(int)index {

    _NSArrayControllerTreeNode* parentNode = item;
    _NSArrayControllerTreeNode* siblingNode;
    _NSControllerTreeProxy* proxy = [ groupTreeControl arrangedObjects ];

    NSManagedObject* draggedGroup = [ draggedNode observedObject ];

    BOOL draggingDown = NO;
    BOOL isRootLevelDrag = NO;

    // ----------------------
    // Setup comparison paths
    // -------------------------
    NSIndexPath* draggedPath = [ draggedNode indexPath ];
    NSIndexPath* siblingPath =  [ NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:  index  ];
    if ( parentNode == NULL ) {     
        isRootLevelDrag = YES;
    } else {
        // A non-root drag - the index value is relative to this parent's children
        siblingPath = [ [ parentNode indexPath ] indexPathByAddingIndex: index ];
    }

    // ----------------------
    // Compare paths - modify sibling path for down drags, exit for redundant drags
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    switch ( [ draggedPath compare:siblingPath] ) {
        case NSOrderedAscending:  // reset path for down dragging
            if ( isRootLevelDrag ) {
                siblingPath = [ NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex: index  - 1];                             
            } else {
                siblingPath = [ [ parentNode indexPath ] indexPathByAddingIndex: index - 1 ]; 
            }
            draggingDown = YES;
            break;

        case NSOrderedSame:
            return NO;
            break;               
    }

    siblingNode = [ proxy nodeAtIndexPath:siblingPath ];    

    //  NSLog(@"returning early");
    //  return NO;  // TODO robustify


    // ------------------------------------------------------------ 
    // SPECIAL CASE: Dragging to the bottom
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // - K                               - K                            - C                              - C
    // - - U                             - - C     OR     - U                                - F
    // - - C     ====>     - - F                    - F                              - K
    // - - F               - U              - K                              - U
    // ------------------------------------------------------------ 
    if ( isRootLevelDrag  && siblingNode == NULL ) {        
        draggingDown = YES;
        siblingPath = [ NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex: [ proxy count ] - 1 ];          
        siblingNode = [ proxy nodeAtIndexPath:siblingPath ] ;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------ 
    // Give the dragged item a position relative to it's new sibling
    // ------------------------------------------------------------ 
    NSManagedObject* sibling = [ siblingNode observedObject ];   
    NSNumber* bystanderPosition = [ sibling valueForKey:@"position"];
    int newPos =   ( draggingDown ? [ bystanderPosition intValue ]  + 1 : [ bystanderPosition intValue ]  - 1 );
    [draggedGroup setValue:[ NSNumber numberWithInt:newPos ] forKey:@"position"];   

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the new parent for the dragged item, resort the position attributes and refresh the tree
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    [ draggedGroup setValue:[ parentNode observedObject ] forKey:@"parent" ];
    [ self resortGroups:[draggedGroup managedObjectContext] forParent:[ parentNode observedObject ] ];          
    [ groupTreeControl rearrangeObjects ];  
    return YES;             
}






- (NSArray* ) getSubGroups:(NSManagedObjectContext*)objectContext forParent:(NSManagedObject*)parent {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"projects" inManagedObjectContext:objectContext];

    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor* aSortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject: aSortDesc] ];
    [aSortDesc release];

    NSPredicate* validationPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent == %@", parent ];

    [ request setPredicate:validationPredicate ];

    NSError *error = nil;  // TODO - check the error bozo
    return [objectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];    
}




- (void) resortGroups:(NSManagedObjectContext*)objectContext forParent:(NSManagedObject*)parent {

    NSArray *array = [ self getSubGroups:objectContext forParent:parent ];

    // Reset the indexes...
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [array objectEnumerator];
    NSManagedObject* anObject;
    int index = 0;
    while (anObject = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        // Multiply index by 10 to make dragging code easier to implement ;) ....
        [anObject setValue:[ NSNumber numberWithInt:(index * INTERVAL ) ] forKey:@"position"];    
        index++;
    }   


}

- (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(int)index {

    _NSArrayControllerTreeNode* newParent = item;

    // drags to the root are always acceptable
    if ( newParent == NULL ) {  
        return  NSDragOperationGeneric; 
    }

    // Verify that we are not dragging a parent to one of it's ancestors
    // causes a parent loop where a group of nodes point to each other and disappear
    // from the control 
    NSManagedObject* dragged = [ draggedNode observedObject ];      
    NSManagedObject* newP = [ newParent observedObject ];

    if ( [ self category:dragged isSubCategoryOf:newP ] ) {
        return NO;
    }       

    return NSDragOperationGeneric;
}

- (BOOL) category:(NSManagedObject* )cat isSubCategoryOf:(NSManagedObject* ) possibleSub {

    // Depends on your interpretation of subCategory ....
    if ( cat == possibleSub ) { return YES; }

    NSManagedObject* possSubParent = [possibleSub valueForKey:@"parent"];   

    if ( possSubParent == NULL ) {  return NO; }

    while ( possSubParent != NULL ) {       
        if ( possSubParent == cat ) { return YES;   }

        // move up the tree
        possSubParent = [possSubParent valueForKey:@"parent"];          
    }   

    return NO;
}

// This method gets called by the framework but the values from bindings are used instead
```

Comment: I'm not sure the information you've provided is sufficient... can you add a stack trace as well?

Comment: The error in the Debugger didn't provide a Stack Trace. How else do i find it?

Comment: In the debugger console, enter “b objc\_exception\_throw” (or add an exception using the exceptions window, Run->Show->Breakpoints). When the debugger breaks, open the debugger window (Run->Debugger). The top left panel will show a stack trace. Somewhere in the stach trace, you’ll see a -copy message; the first entry in black under that is the point in your code that’s triggering the problem.

Comment: 'backtrace' or 'bt' at the GDB console

Comment: I tried typing that in but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you add the exact text of the error message to this question?

Comment: Why do you want the text when  you can see it in the Picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error should provide the name of the class that received the unrecognized method and the unrecognized method that was sent.

(1) If you recognize the method name -- if you have written a line (or lines) of code that calls that method -- review the line(s) of code and make sure that the target of the method call is valid, is of the correct type, and hasn't been over released somewhere else.

Often, an unrecognized method invocation error is caused when you have over-released an object somewhere and a new object of the wrong type has taken up residence in the memory of the old object.

(2) If you didn't write a call to that method, then you have other supplied the wrong type of object to some framework method or, again, you have over-released something.

If you suspect over-release, turn on NSZombies or use the Zombie tracking feature in Instruments (yeah, what Peter said).

So, the error is `NSTreeControllerTreeNode ... doesn't respond to -copyWithZone:`.

Almost guarantee that indicates that you have tried to shove a tree controller tree node into a dictionary somewhere as a key and the dictionary is trying to copy it.  At least, that is most typically what happens.

This still could be an over-release problem where an instance of NSTreeControllerTreeNode happens to be sitting in memory where an NSString used to be.

Search the Xcode documentation for `NSZombie` for more information on turning it on in your current version of the dev tools.

Comment: I think it must be No.2. When I go to the "Run with Performance Tool" menu there is no Zombies option as you can see here - http://www.grabup.com/uploads/56e2b7a108333326d1acc6bfdde7d064.png?direct

Comment: Well, there may be a Zombies template in some hypothetical future version of Xcode, but there is not in 3.1.3. ☺

Comment: What else I noticed is that if I get rid of the code from the first question the App runs fine with no problem. So the problem has to be some where in that code.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTreeControllerTreeNode` isn't a standard Cocoa class.

Did you mean to use `NSTreeController` or `NSTreeNode` instead?

Comment: That's the thing, I haven't actually used it. What I noticed was that when I got rid of the code (the code in the first post) the App ran without a hitch, so the problem must be in the code from the first post. And I haven't use NSTreeControllerTreeNode there.

Comment: Okay, then when you remove the code, what then becomes the datasource of the outline view?

Comment: The other code I have in the Datasource file. Should I post that too?

Comment: Could the other code in the Datasource be something to do with the error?